# How to change Quartus II default 5000 integer iterations

Tags: compilation, verilog, intel, fpga, quartus

Error(13356) loop must terminate within 5000 iterations Quartus II

Comment: Don't change the iteration limit, fix your code. Unless you have an extremely large design, you shouldn't be getting anywhere near 5000 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

change the iteration limit by:

Assignment -> Settings -> Compile settings -> advanced settings (Synthesis) -> Iteration limit for constant Verilog loops

Version: 18.1